# Wrong DDL statement order: dropping index before dropping related foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to update a target database with SQL Server Data Tools, using the **Publish** option. I've got both pre-deployment and post-deployment scripts with custom instructions.

Here's the problem: SSDT tries to drop an index `numero` from my target that doesn't exist in my reference schema, but fails because it is being used for foreign key enforcement by constraint `fk_numero`. This foreign key is being dropped later in the script since there's another change to be made on this table.

I have considered dropping `fk_numero` in my pre-deploy script, but it would fail anyway because of the `DROP CONSTRAINT fk_numero` that is called later in the generated script: since SSDT doesn't write `IF EXISTS` tests before dropping a constraint, it fails when trying to delete something that doesn't exist.

I have also tried to disable all foreign keys in my pre-deploy script with a `NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL`, hoping I'd then be able to drop my index, to no avail.

Is there an option in SSDT to specify whether you want it to generate `DROP CONSTRAINT` scripts? Or an option for instructions order? Or a way to hint to SSDT that it should test whether the constraint exists before trying to drop it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the "DROP objects in target but not in Project" option.

Are you using custom-made scripts to modify the schema?

Comment: I presume that's what the OP meant by "SSDT tries to drop an index numero from my target that doesn't exist in my reference schema"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've just tried to check this option but the outcome is still the same. 

As I said, I use a custom-made pre-deployment script in which I apply various changes to the target schema, things like dropping columns or indexes but none that has a link to the error (as far as I can see). Anyway the error occurs after my custom script, at an auto-generated line.

Comment: OK, the custom script can not be taken into acount when ssdt generates its publish script, I would guess that is why the error appears.

Comment: @SAS: yes, I'm aware of that. That's why I can't drop the constraint myself before the publish script runs. But I wonder why SSDT can't be smart enough to drop it before dropping the index, whereas it is indeed smart enough to do it in other cases (like modifying something on the column).

Comment: Well, if SSDT can't publish automatically then I would create the script myself, making it rerunnable. And also report to MS. Also think about posting a script, so we can try to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue when working with SSDT. Turns out it's a known [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/818980/changing-an-index-is-not-allowed-when-it-is-being-used-for-foreign-key-constraint-enforcement), which was reported on Microsoft Connect. However, it doesn't seem to have been resolved.

UPDATE:

The [May 2015 Update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/05/18/sql-server-data-tools-update-for-may-2015.aspx) for SSDT includes a fix for this issue.